# delphi 2009 cast to string length 2

Tags: string, delphi, casting, delphi-2009

looking how to suppress a warning from the compiler that says possible data loss,

```
st:= copy(str,0,2);
```

where st is string[2] and str has more then 2 chars.

and copy is defied as from str return a new string that is a subset from 0 , 2 places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just write:

```
st := shortstring(str);
```

The compiler will do the work for you.

It will cut `str` content to fit the maximum length of `st`. So if `st` is defined as `st: string[2];` if will retrieve only the 2 first characters of `str`.

But you may loose non ascii encoded characters in str (not a problem if it does contain only English text).

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, but you're wrong. If the current code page of his system is not WinAnsi (i.e. 1252) but for instance an asiatic MBCS code page, he could possibly loose also Ansi characters if the source str contains latin accents e.g.: only 7 bit ASCII and unicode characters handled by the current code page will be converted as expected into the shortstring content.

Answer (score 5):

This will suppress the warning, but beware the underlying issue is still there: Converting from Unicode to AnsiString can cause lose of data.

```
st := ShortString(Copy(str,1,2));
```

And don't forget Delphi stings are 1-based, the first char in the string is 1, not 0.

Comment: +1. If the compiler is warning you about an *implicit* cast, then tell the compiler that it is intentional by making the cast *explicit*.

Comment: string[2] is made up of ansichars. It is a shortstring type. I wonder if the OP knows that.

Comment: @none: You probably mean the opposite: `string` to `string[2]`. In Delphi 2009, the standard `string` is Unicode (thank God!), but `string[2]` is a so-called `ShortString`, which is non-Unicode, only one byte per character. So `st` cannot hold, for instance, the string `∰∂`, even though it contains only two characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your use is wrong you have to do :

```
st:= copy(str,1,2);
```

Comment: There will still be a warning from the Delphi 2009+ compiler here, about an implicit string type cast. It expects at least an explicit one.

Comment: oh... OK I couldn't see it because I have D7